# How to use matter.js in a module

Tags: module, matter.js

Beginner question here. I need to implement matter.js into a project built within a module. When I try a simple import like this:

```
import  "./matter.js";
```

I get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Matter' of undefined
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (VM609 matter.js:36)
    at VM609 matter.js:37
```

What is the proper way to do this? Sorry if this is a newbie question. Just can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Are you using browser modules or Node modules? Where did you get `matter.js` from? Normally, if you want to use MJS in Node, you `npm install matter-js`, then import with `import "matter-js"`. It sounds like the error is that you have a browser MJS trying to attach itself to the window, with `window.Matter = {}` which is going to crash in Node.

Answer (score 1):

Replace line 37 in the matter.js file with

```
})(this || window, function() {
```

instead of

```
})(this, function() {
```

and then just say

```
import './matter.js';

Matter.whatever;
```

Seems to work for me at least!